# How to increment training Theano saved models?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, theano

I have a trained model by [Theano](http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/), and there are new training data I want to increase the mode, How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the model with the pre-trained weights and perform gradient updates for the new examples, but you do have to take care of the learning rate and other parameters (depending on your optimizer). You may also try storing optimizer's parameter as well, initializing the optimizer with those values of parameters to make sure new training data does not drastically change the trained model.